# normalization image before using ssd_mobilenet

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, database-normalization, object-detection-api, pre-trained-model

I try train ssd-mobilenet in my own dataset : 
training image : 3400 with size :1600*1200 
test set :800 with size :1600 *1200 tensorflow -gpu :1.13.1 gpu :4GB cuda 10.0 cudnn 7 
object: road damage like aligator crack but after 197000 step my training loss cannot go down 2.
I have 2 questions
Should I normalize my training and set image before before using pretrained model like ssd_mobilenet?
If yes
Should I annotate images normalized or not ?
I need really helps. Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you using the TF object detection API to train the model?

Comment: yes i use tensorflow object detection API

Answer (score 1):

> Should I normalize my training and set image before before using pretrained model like ssd_mobilenet?

No. Assuming you define your training pipeline correctly (see the examples in the TF Models repository), the Object detection API will take care of defining the appropriate image transformations (scaling, padding, normalization, etc) required in order to make the input compatible with the model.

Comment: Ok but why my training loss is slow to converge .Thanks for your help

Comment: "after 197000 step my training loss cannot go down", seems to me your network converged. In my experience, for small datasets 200k steps is quite a lot when it comes to fine-tuning. Whether your network converged to an acceptable performance level is a different issue (is the model the most appropriate for the task you're tackling? Is your dataset hard to detect? Is the default network configuration good for you? etc)

Comment: thanks. for the model i think yes since i try to train my model like  https://github.com/sekilab/RoadDamageDetector but their images size is 600*600 .I use the default configuration .